# How to make the plot mark size independent of the scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf

the next code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [yscale=2]
\draw [very thin, lightgray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw [cyan] plot [only marks, mark=square*,mark size=2.5pt] coordinates {(1,1) (2,3) (2.5,2)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

**How to avoid the distorsion of the marks?**

Comment: I admit that I do not see the distortion in the screenshot... However, it might help if you place `scale=2` as option somewhere in your `\draw [cyan] plot [...]` statement (plot marks are drawn after the path as such; perhaps they reset parts of the transformation matrix)

Comment: You can add `mark options={yscale=0.5}`.

Comment: I made a mistake when I uploaded the file. Jake gave the solution in a comment and I wait for his answer because I think it's interesting to know his method. I try your idea but without success with `[yscale=2]` first and then `yscale=1/2` in the `plot` options. The shape is fine but the coordinates are wrong.

Comment: @percusse Fine idea, I try `yscale=.5` in the options of `plot` but I forgot `mark options={yscale=0.5}`. I prefer Jake's method but your idea is interesting. Perhaps you can  transform your comment in an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but Jake has nailed it. No need for an additional hack :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a style `scale plot marks` that, if set to `false`, will patch the `\pgfuseplotmark` command to reset all transformations that don't influence the position (including scaling). The change is kept local.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    scale plot marks/.is choice,
    scale plot marks/false/.code={
        \def\pgfuseplotmark##1{\pgftransformresetnontranslations\csname pgf@plot@mark@##1\endcsname}
    },
    scale plot marks/true/.style={},
    scale plot marks/.default=true
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [yscale=2]
\node [align=center, anchor=north] at (2,4) {\verb|scale plot marks=true|\\(default)};
\draw [very thin, lightgray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw [cyan] plot [only marks, mark=square*,mark size=2.5pt] coordinates {(1,1) (2,3) (2.5,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} [yscale=2]
\node [align=center, anchor=north] at (2,4) {\verb|scale plot marks=false|};
\draw [very thin, lightgray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw [cyan] plot [only marks, mark=square*,mark size=2.5pt,scale plot marks=false] coordinates {(1,1) (2,3) (2.5,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, like this, it's a pleasure to use your method!